# Select from multiple tables without getting Parameter error

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

I am currently trying to code a database project for a musicians record log. I have been struggling to join 3 tables together in a single search of the database and I am getting this error:

**No value given for one or more required parameters.**

I have been searching online for why this is but cannot find anything which quite fixes my code. I have tried copying almost word for word other syntax but still get this error. Any help would be much appreciated, my database is as follows:

```
Program(ProgramID(PK), LengthOfProgram, UserName, NameOfProgram) 
ProgramList(PieceListID(PK), PieceID(FK), ProgramID(FK))
Repertoire(PieceID(PK), NameOfPiece, Composer)
```

Those are the fields needed from repertoire.

Here is my code for when the the program is selected from the list box.

```vb
Public dtbConnecter As New OleDbConnection
Dim fileLocator As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & "Data Source = " + Application.StartupPath + "\Musician Record Log.accdb"

Private Sub lstPro_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lstPro.SelectedIndexChanged

    Dim programID As String
    Dim programIDLength As Integer
    Dim selectedString As String = lstPro.GetItemText(lstPro.SelectedItem)
    programIDLength = selectedString.IndexOf(":")
    programID = selectedString.Substring(0, programIDLength)
    MsgBox(programID)

    Dim SQL As String = "Select Program.ProgramName, Program.ProgramLength, Repertoire.NameOfPiece, Repertoire.Composer From ((ProgramList INNER JOIN Repertoire ON ProgramList.PieceID = Repertoire.PieceID) INNER JOIN Program ON ProgramList.ProgramID = Program.ProgramID) WHERE (Program.ProgramID = @Param1)"
    Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim dtbTable As New DataTable
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim dtbCommand As New OleDbCommand
    dtbCommand.Parameters.Add("@Param1", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = programID
    dtbCommand.Connection = dtbConnecter
    dtbCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text

    dtbCommand.CommandText = SQL
    da.SelectCommand = dtbCommand
    da.Fill(dtbTable)

    'Here i would then use the table's information to update my form, however first i'm trying to get this to work. 

    da.Dispose()
    da = Nothing

End Sub
```

I also import `System.Data`, `System.Data.OleDb` and `System.Drawing.Imaging` at the top.

Comment: I think it's just all those parenthesis in your sql throwing off the syntax. It doesn't look like you need any of them. Also I would recommend the `Using` statement for your connections. They will be disposed automatically that way you don't have to handle them manually.

Comment: If you paste the query into an Access SQL window with an ID in place of Param, does it work?  You might want to look into DataBinding - using a DataSource you can show one thing to the user and have a Combo or ListBox provide your code with another (like the ID) so you dont have to tediously parse bits of data out of strings as that does

Comment: @JacobH thank you for the suggestion, after taking out all brackets, there was a different error, and when I searched that error, I found that for multiple inner join's you need brackets around each one, I will look into the access SQL window now

Comment: You are right, I forgot it was access SQL. In that case, the problem would be the first set of parenthesis are messing with the from clause. Check this page for the syntax: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/inner-join-operation-b9e73ab6-884a-403e-9f22-cb502feae36a

Comment: Is programID really a VarChar? Many times a PK is an Integer with auto-increment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was just a stupid mistake, the names of the fields in the database are NameOfProgram and LengthOfProgram but in the SQL query I used ProgramName and ProgramLength, thanks for all the help in ensuring the SQL query was correct and I did need to correct the data type but the main problem was the wrong identifier.